# C# proper use of Dispose with SafeSocketHandle

Tags: c#, sockets, dispose, finalizer

Im aware of the [dispose pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) and would like to properly dispose my Socket resource. 
In the documentation they recommend to use [SafeHandles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle), but I'm not sure how exactly this works with [System.Net.Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket). I discovered that the Socket class itself includes a [SafeSocketHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.safehandle), but I have no idea how to use it. Do I need to dispose the handle and the socket or is it sufficient to dispose only the handle? And I assume in the class I'm only using the handle for socket operations, right?

```
public class MySocket : IDisposable
{
    private SafeSocketHandle _handle;
    private bool _disposed = false;

    public MySocket(AddressFamily addressFamily)
    {
        Socket s = new Socket(addressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        _handle = s.SafeHandle;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            _handle.Dispose();
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

And maybe someone is also able to explain why SafeHandles should be used?
I mean wouldn't this be sufficient?:

```
public class MySocket : IDisposable
{
    private Socket _socket;
    private bool _disposed = false;

    public MySocket(AddressFamily addressFamily)
    {
        _socket = new Socket(addressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            _socket.Dispose();
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you've missed the finalizers off your code sample -- they're important.

Comment: @canton7 Is not the hole point of the pattern to avoid working with the finalizer directly?  Also in this example they don't implement the finalizer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose#using-a-safe-handle-to-implement-the-dispose-pattern-for-a-base-class

Comment: The point of `SafeHandle` is to avoid users shooting themselves in the foot when they try and release unmanaged resources. It's true that if you're using a `SafeHandle`, you don't need to implement the full dispose pattern, see my answer. But if you *are* implementing the full dispose pattern, you need to do it properly. In your code, `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` does nothing (since you don't have a finalizer), and nothing ever calls your `void Dispose(bool disposing)` method with `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `SafeHandle` when you are directly managing an unmanaged resource.

With `Socket`, there is an underlying unmanaged resource, but that's handled by the `Socket` class. There's no need for you to get involved in it -- `Socket` itself is a managed resource, not an unmanaged resource. `Socket` has its own finalizer, which will (may) release the underlying unmanaged resource if you forget to dispose it.

So, here you don't need to worry about `SafeHandles`. Just implement `IDisposable` and call `_socket.Dispose()`.

---

You don't *need* to implement the full Dispose pattern here, unless you might have a derived class which owns its own unmanaged resources. It's sufficient to write:

```
public class MySocket : IDisposable
{
    private Socket _socket;
    private bool _disposed = false;

    public MySocket(AddressFamily addressFamily)
    {
        _socket = new Socket(addressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _socket.Dispose();
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Indeed, many coding standards mandate that unmanaged resources **must** be wrapped in a `SafeHandle`. If you do this, there's no need to ever implement the full Dispose pattern.

If you **do** need to implement the full dispose pattern, you also need to write a finalizer. The code in your question doesn't do this.

In fact, the dispose pattern encourages users down quite a dangerous path -- writing correct code in your `void Dispose(bool disposing)` method is really quite hard, and there are pitfalls which most users aren't aware of. This is why `SafeHandle` was introduced in .NET 2.0 -- the runtime has special support for it which avoids those pitfalls -- but the advice around `IDisposable` seems to have never been updated.

Comment: Now it's clearer to me. Thanks! So basically I could use the SafeHandle to avoid implementing the finalizer. But because Socket takes care of the unmanaged resources I don't need a SafeHandle. Therefore the simple disposing is sufficient. But could you do me a favour and explain me very simple what the unmanaged resources in this case are and how Socket takes care of them? This would help me in future to decide if I need a SafeHandle

Comment: Not that `SafeHandle` does more than just letting you avoid writing a finalizer: it avoids some pitfalls around releasing unmanaged resources. For example, did you know that your class can be finalized *while one of its methods is executing*? That means that you can close a handle while a native function is using it, which is very bad. `Socket` is a particularly complicated example -- `FileStream` is a lot easier. [Read the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,e23a38af5d11ddd3), look at how `_handle` is used.